# refrain/ restrain or abstain from physical activity?

Tags: word-choice

I need help with this sentence: 
"Based on the above condition the patient should restrain/ refrain or abstain from physical activity"?
Which verb is the best choice?

Comment: I go for **"refrain"**

Answer (score 2):

According to Cambridge.

- *Abstain* - to not do something, especially something enjoyable that you think might be bad.
- *Refrain* - to avoid doing or stop yourself from doing something.
- *Restrain* - to control the actions or behaviour of someone by force, especially in order to stop them from doing something, or to limit the growth or force of something

As you can see, the best choice is **"refrain"**.

Comment: refrain from physical activity, abstain from sex, alcohol, and tobacco.

Comment: @JohnFeltz You forgot **restrain**

Comment: restrain your dog from licking his stitches  :-)

Comment: I had to abstain from refraining restraining the young boy. Possible?

Answer (score 1):

To my non-native ears:

*abstain from* works better for situations potentially **tempting**, or typically/basically **necessary**:

> abstained from altercation to maintain his calm within

or

> from time to time, abstains from food for a week, as a spiritual practice

*refrain from* fits better, cases where one has the discretion to **opt for** or **against** an act, like:

> refrained from giving a clear answer

and *restrict [oneself] from* sits well primarily in contexts where one is **forced into** a(n undesirable) situation, such as:

> restrict oneself from yawning in a morning class.

As for your case, I think *restrict himself/herself from physical activity* is out, according to the above argument. *Refrain from* sounds more natural, I guess, unless the patient is so into physical exercising that they will find it difficult to stop doing it for a while; if this is the case,or one along these lines, you may use *abstain from*.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct that "refrain" is the best choice, but it should also be noted that "refrain" is a verb that requires both a preposition **and** a gerund (an "ing" verb). So a better expression than "refrain from physical activity" is "refrain from engaging (that's the gerund) in physical activity."
One refrains "from doing" something. We refrain from eating the whole cake; we refrain from shouting in a library; we refrain from laughing when someone falls down (or at least we try to refrain from doing so).

Comment: Could you please comment also on _avoid physical activity_? thank you for your time